# "else if()" versus multiple "if()"s in C#

Tags: c#

How do these practically differ?

```
// Approach one
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
else if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();

// Approach two
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();
```

Is the resulting CIL the same?

<sub>(The question *[Use of “if/elseif/else” versus “if/else{if/else}”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518256/use-of-if-elseif-else-versus-if-elseif-else)* exists, but it is yet to be answered.)</sub>

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If `DoSomething` sets `x` to 2, then they will differ.

Comment: Thank, you. So including `else` will contain the scope of the overall if so that it executes atomically. This makes sense to me. I should have thought of it. Cheers.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT: Something like that!  Grammatically speaking, the first approach is identical to `if(...) { ... } else { if(...) { ... } }`.

Answer (score 25):

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    Int32 x = 1;

    if (x == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    else if (x == 2)
        Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Results in:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor()
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0001: stloc.0 
    L_0002: ldloc.0 
    L_0003: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0004: bne.un.s L_0011
    L_0006: ldstr "1"
    L_000b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0010: ret 
    L_0011: ldloc.0 
    L_0012: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0013: bne.un.s L_001f
    L_0015: ldstr "2"
    L_001a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_001f: ret 
}
```

While:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    Int32 x = 1;

    if (x == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("1");

    if (x == 2)
        Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Results in:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor()
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0001: stloc.0 
    L_0002: ldloc.0 
    L_0003: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0004: bne.un.s L_0010
    L_0006: ldstr "1"
    L_000b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0010: ldloc.0 
    L_0011: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0012: bne.un.s L_001e
    L_0014: ldstr "2"
    L_0019: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_001e: ret 
}
```

IL code is a little bit different and here is the main difference:

```
Approach One: L_0004: bne.un.s L_0011 -> L_0011: ldloc.0 with L_0010: ret 
Approach Two: L_0004: bne.un.s L_0010 -> L_0010: ldloc.0 with no ret in between
```

When you use else statement, as in first approach, only the first branch that meets the condition will be run. On the other hand... with the second approach every check is processed and every check that meets the condition will be followed and processed. That's the main difference.

That's why in the first approach's IL code you have a "ret" directive just after the call of Console.WriteLine while in the second it's not present. In the first case the method can be exited just after a check has been passed because no more checks on `x` will be performed... in the second approach you have to follow all of them sequentially and that's why ret is only appearing at the end of the method, no "shortcuts" to the end.

For my test i used a `Console.WriteLine()` call... but it's sure that if `DoSomething()` involves a value change of `x` variable, the difference will be absolutely more important in the code behavior. Let's say that we have x as a private static member (initial value always 1) instead of a local variable and:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    ++m_X;
}
```

In the first approach, even if `m_X` assumes a value of 2 after `DoSomething()` is called thanks to the first check, else will make the method exit and `DoSomethingElse()` will never be called. In the second approach both methods will be called.

Comment: Plus one for detailed answer covering entire topic. I've been searching for performance breakdowns on this topic.

Answer (score 16):

Note that there is no `else if` construct in C#. Your first code sample is exactly the same as:

```
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
else 
{
    if (x == 2)
        DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Since there is only one statement in `else`, the braces can be omitted, and for enhanced readability, `if` is usually written on the same line as the preceding `else`. Writing multiple "`else if`" statements is equivalent to further nesting:

```
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
else 
{
    if (x == 2)
        DoSomethingElse();
    else
    {
        if (x == 3)
            YetSomethingElse();
        else
        {
            if (x == 4)
               ReallyDifferent();
        }
    }
}
```

The above can be written as:

```
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
else if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();
else if (x == 3)
    YetSomethingElse();
else if (x == 4)
    ReallyDifferent();
```

From this, you can see that chaining "`else if`" and `if` can produce different results. In case of "`else if`", the first branch that satisfies the condition will be executed, and after that no further checks are done. In case of chained `if` statements, all branches that satisfy their conditions are executed.

The main difference here is when execution of a branch causes a subsequent condition to become true. For example:

```
   var x = 1;

   if (x == 1)
       x = 2;
   else if (x == 2)
       x = 3;
```

VS

```
   var x = 1;

   if (x == 1)
       x = 2;

   if (x == 2)
       x = 3;
```

In the first case, `x == 2`, while in the second case `x == 3`.

Answer (score 10):

*When you code like this*

```
// approach two
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();
```

**Everytime the condition checks.**

*But when you code like this*

```
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();
else if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();
```

**If the first condition is true then it wont check next else if condition and thus decrease unnecessary compiling**.

Comment: Thank you, Ravi. I appreciate your contribution to this discussion. And, you are 100% correct. That's how it works.

Comment: you mean decrease unecessary checks. Because compilation-wise I don't see what will decrease!

Answer (score 5):

When you use `else` statement, only one of the branches will be run (i.e. the first, which meets the `if` condition). All other `if` conditions won't even be estimated:

```
// approach one
int x = 1;
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething(); //only this will be run, even if `DoSomething` changes `x` to 2
else if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();
```

While when you don't use it each of them may be run (depending on each of the conditions), i.e. each of them is estimated one by one:

```
// approach two
int x = 1;
if (x == 1)
    DoSomething();//this is run, as `x` == 1
if (x == 2)
    DoSomethingElse();//if `DoSomething` changes `x` to 2, this is run as well
```

So, IL may differ.

Answer (score 5):

No anwsers about performance?

So if x=1 then you do only one check in first case, and in second case you do 2 checks, so  first case is faster.

Answer (score 5):

Else if will only be evaluated if the first condition wasn't true. But two consecutive if statements will both be evaluated.

You can easily test this concept in a [Python interpreter](https://repl.it/languages/python3):

First run this:

Note: In Python elif is used instead of else if

```
a = 1
if a >= 1:
  print('a is greater than or equal to 1')
elif a<=1:
  print('a is less than or equal to 1')
```

then run this

```
a=1
if a >= 1:
  print('a is greater than or equal to 1')
if a<=1:
  print('a is less than or equal to 1')
```

Answer (score 3):

If x changes (in Do Seomthing and DoSomethingElse) then the first statement will only ever execute one statement. In the 2nd example every statement will be checked (unless of course the compiler optimizes it to a jump table for number comparison).

Answer (score 3):

When you use multiple `else if`, it will execute the condition that meets. If there are remaining cases, they will be skipped. When you have multiple `if`, it will check every statement. So this becomes more of a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is modified by multiple threads it is possible that `DoSomething()` and `DoSomethingElse()` will both get called with the second approach