# C# else if confusion

Tags: c#

I am currently studying the conditional constructions. Correct me if I am wrong but else if and else(if(){}) is the same thing... Example:

```
a=5;
if(a==6)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine("Variable 'a' is 6");
}
else if(a==5)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Variable 'a' is 5");
}
```

And

```
a=5;
if(a==6)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Variable 'a' is 6");
}
else
{
    if(a==5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Variable 'a' is 5");
    }
}
```

Are these things the same? And if yes why does else if exist if I can write it the "second way"(the second example that I wrote)?

Comment: No, they're not the same. They have the same effect in your example, but what if you had a third else if condition?

Comment: @TZHX I would have to write another else{if(){}} ? Or i can't have 2 elses can I?

Comment: @peter: And what would that look like?  And what would it look like if you added even more conditions?

Comment: And then another if inside it, and another else containing another if. Can you see how many more curly brackets that would lead to?

Comment: @TZHX so else if is another way of writing it for a better visual experience?

Comment: Not just for the visual experience, but because it more clearly demonstrates what you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518256/use-of-if-elseif-else-versus-if-elseif-else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these are effectively identical.

The reason the "else if" statement exists is to make cleaner code when there are many conditions to test for.  For example:

```
if (a==b) {
   //blah
} else if (a==c) {
   //blah
} else if (a==d) {
   //blah
} else if (a==e) {
   //blah
}
```

is much cleaner than the nested approach

```
if (a==b) { 
    //blah
} else {    
    if (a==c) {
        //blah
    } else {
        if (a==d) {
            //blah
        } else {
            if (a==e) {
                //blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though lets be honest, cases like that are what `switch` is for.

Comment: You can't always use switch case-- like in my example, c, d, and e are variables, not constants, so you can't use them in case statements.

Comment: @Tim ok but can't i add all those ifs in only one else construnction? so it would look something like this `if (a==b) { 
    //blah
} else {    
    if (a==c) {
        //blah }
        if (a==d) {
            //blah }
            if (a==e) {
                //blah
            }
}`

Comment: @peter It depends on the logic you want to implement. Your suggestion is totally different from the example in this answer

Comment: @peter What happens if c==d? then you end up running both id a==c and if a==d with only the one else, and if you want to do that, then you are just testing the variable each time and there is no need for an else.

Comment: @Tim fair point, but I don't tend to see many tests like that, with that many elses testing variable against variable.

Comment: I think they should add in the newbie programming books that else if comes from the fact that it uses the advantage of not using brackets if after the else statement you have only one line....

Comment: @peter Possibly. It's not a necessary detail, though, since newbie books are designed to teach the basics, not the implementation details. I prefer leaving things like this out of the intro lessons, not just because of information overload, but also to leave epiphany opportunities like this later on. (There's also the fact that there are other languages where there *is* an "else if" keyword, like `elif` in Python for example.)

Comment: @Abion47 is it like bash ? PS i like to understand where things come from even though i'm a newbie

Comment: @peter All newbie books should contain the sentence *Read The Docs* => [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) => *Both the then-statement and the else-statement can consist of a single statement or multiple statements that are enclosed in braces ({}). For a single statement, the braces are optional but recommended.*

Answer (score 3):

> why does `else if` exist

It doesn't.  It's not a keyword or construct on its own.  Your two examples are identical except that in the second case you've added some superfluous braces and whitespace into the code.

`if` and `else` are both simply followed by a single statement.  In your first example the statement following the `else` is:

```
 if(a==5)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Variable 'a' is 5");
}
```

The second example just wraps that same statement in braces, and adds a new line at the start.  The new line is ignored, so it doesn't change the semantics, and as the code is *already* a single statement, wrapping it in braces doesn't change it in any way.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh now i get it ... So basically "else if" is just using advantage that you don't need to use braces if it's a single line? And that why else { if(){}} == else if ?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as an `else if` statement. An "else if" is actually just in essence an `else` with a single line body that happens to be the start of an entirely separate `if` statement. You can visualize it like this:

```
var a = 5;

// This if uses a single line
if (a == 6) DoSomething();
// This else is a single line that is also a single-line if
else if (a == 4) DoAnotherThing();
// This else uses a single line as well, but is referring instead to the second if
else DoSomethingElse();
```

The above script is identical to the following:

```
if (a == 6) 
{
    DoSomething();
}
else 
{
    if (a == 4) 
    {
        DoAnotherThing();
    }
    else 
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Or even this:

```
if (a == 6) 
    DoSomething();
else 
    if (a == 4) 
        DoAnotherThing();
    else 
        DoSomethingElse();
```

The reason that it is written as `else if` so commonly is because it compliments the logical flow of the code. That, and it just looks so much prettier.

Comment: The last statement should be reworded to "DoSomethingCompletelyDifferent" - just kidding :o)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it makes the code cleaner, easier to read, makes indenting better, particularly if you have any conventions on character length of rows (and if you don't then you've got thirty indents in a big if statement, such a pain to read). It also saves space, a few extra characters and indents across thousands of lines may not be much, but why use it if you don't have to. When the code compiles they will pretty much be the exact same in the DLLs anyways.